# Index & sort with newly introduced field

Tags: node.js, database, sorting, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I have a document structure as below:

```
{
  "_id": "6ed3d427045228dce9e3b38d111cb046",
  "_rev": "1-952bddae5572fbf2b0ce4a165c19c98b",
  "type": "USER",
  "name": "ABC",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "phone": "024578963"
}
```

This is NodeJS app and I am using the `couchdb-nano`. For the sorting purpose (like getting data for Pagination), I have created an index for the above fields (`name`, `email`, `phone`).

A new field called `created_date` has been introduced to the documents and all the latest documents contains the `created_date` as below:

```
{
  "_id": "6ed3d427045228dce9e3b38d111cb046",
  "_rev": "1-952bddae5572fbf2b0ce4a165c19c98b",
  "type": "USER",
  "name": "ABC",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "phone": "024578963",
  "created_date": 1570528394252
}
```

So that all the latest documents since a certain time consist the `created_date` and old documents has no `created_date` field in the document.

When I try to sort like below:

```
const q = {
      selector : {
        type: { "$eq": "USER" },
      },
      fields : ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'created_date'],
      limit: 100,
      skip: 10,
      sort : [{"created_date":"asc"}]
    };
await prodresdb.find(q);
```

I will not be able to get old documents that are not consist the `created_date`. 
This is because of `created_date` index will not index the old documents since those has no `created_date` field.

I am sure someone else have this problem too and need to figure out... How to overcome this? Is there any CouchDB way to fix this? What is the best practice for such kind of problem.

Comment: what do u want to incase of old documents that does not have `created_date`? Do you want index those old documents also?

Comment: @arunp9294 Yes I need to index with `created_date` those old documents.

Comment: Do you have created_date for users some where?..if you don't have,the way i would fix will be writing a view to get all the user docs without created_date and bulk update all the docs with with created_date (May be with oldest  created_date available in the database)

Comment: `created_date` added after thousands of docs added into the Database

Answer (score 1):

I did a few tests and found that `CouchDB` simply doesn't include documents in the [_find](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html) result if they don't contain the field (attribute) specified in `sort`. In my opinion, this is a bug since `sort` unexpectedly reduces the filtered result. This is especially annoying when using `CouchDB` together with [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) because the latter works as expected (also returns documents with missing attributes).

Adding the missing attribute to existing documents as suggested in a comment above may solve your problem. In many cases however (i.e. for number and boolean attributes), it's not a viable solution because the document content may be falsified.

The **short answer** to your question: In many cases, there's no straight forward `CouchDB` way to fix this.

**UPDATE:**

It's interesting that similar product `Couchbase Server` addresses this issue - for full text search results - by allowing for [fine-grained control over the sort-procedure](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/fts/fts-sorting.html#fts-advanced-sort-options) through the `missing` field.

> **missing**: Specifies the sort-procedure for documents with a missing
>   value in a field specified for sorting. The value of missing can be
>   first, in which case results with missing values appear before other
>   results; or last (the default), in which case they appear after.